# Testing an angularjs directive which manipulates the DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm a complete beginner to Karma, so forgive me if it's a stupid question.

I'm testing a dirctive of mine, which is peculiar two ways:

1 - It conditionally changes template based on the scope content and recompiles the directive element inside the linker

```
var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
//...

var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
            var template = '';

            switch(contentType) {
            case 'canvas':
                template = '<div> stuff here </div>';
                break;
            case 'div':
                template = '<div> other stuff here </div>';
                break;
                //...
             }

            return template;
        };

var html = getTemplate(scope.content.uiType);
            var ae = angular.element(html);

            element.replaceWith(ae);
            $compile(ae)(scope);

}
```

2 - it uses jsplumb in the linker to agument the directive element and set some jsplumb endpoints:

```
// Inside the linker function

var outEndPoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint (ae, { /* parameters */ }, AudioOutPoint);
```

The problem arises when jsPlumb.addEndpoint gets called. Debugging the library, it seems that at a certain point, jsPlumb uses jQuery to return a certain element - the one which it created - by id, along the lines of  $("#jsplumb-element");

jQuery in turn executes tis line:

```
elem = document.getElementById( match[2] );
```

and getElementById returns null (maybe because there's no real DOM?). At this point, an exception is raised and everything comes crashing down.

To be clear: If I set a breakpoint to this statement, and do `document.getElementsByTagName('div');` in the console, it will return  `null`.

I'm using Chrome to test this directive, and the simple test code is as such:

```
describe('Directive: hyPluginWindow', function () {

    beforeEach(module('hyacinthHostApp'));

    var element, $compile, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));


  it('should set the right audioDestinations', inject(function () {

      scope.content = {
          name: "testElement",
          id: "testElement000",
          uiType: "canvas",
          audioIn: 0,
          audioOut: 1,
          audioSources: [],
          audioDestinations: []
      };

      var grandparent = angular.element('<div id="pluginArea"></div>');
      var parent =  angular.element('<div class="plugin"></div>');
      var element = angular.element('<div hy-plugin-window content="content"></div>');
      grandparent.append(parent);
      parent.append(element);
      debugger;
      element = $compile(element)(scope);

      expect(scope.audioDestinations.length).toBe(1);

  }));
});
```

The expect part is never met, because the directive excepts as soon as it's linked.
Please note that, in the application, this code works fine (so the problem lies in the test directive).

What am I missing?

Comment: Pardon asking the obvious, but have you included jquery in karma.config.js? There's some oddness that can crop up as a result of jqlite masking the absence of jQuery in karma tests.

Comment: Yes, I did. If I debug the whole lot and step into the function calls, developer tools will enter the jquery code. The problem seems to be that there's nothing in the DOM. If I set a breakpoint before it breaks, and do `document.getElementsByTagName('div');`, it will return  `null`.

Comment: Hmm. As an alternative to using getTemplate to conditionally select the template HTML, you could move that switch into the template itself using ng-switch. Karma seems to handle that just fine, so if it still blew up, you'd at least know your problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append the element to DOM, in your test, do something like:

```
grandparent.appendTo(document.body);
```

Btw. the plugin you are using should not do `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` and rather do `element.find(...)`. Then, you don't have to append it to DOM, which will makes the test run faster.

Comment: As far as I know, jsPlumb does `$("#jsplumb-element");`, which in turn translates in `document.getElementById('jsplumb-element')` inside jQuery. `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` was an example statement I used in the console to demonstrate my problem. Your point still stands, I guess.

Comment: Yep, doing `$("#x");` is the same thing - it searches in the document rather in the root element. The point is, if it searched in the root element (using `.find()` or something similar), you wouldn't have to append it to the DOM in order to make it work...

Comment: If only jqLite but still dealing with third party library searching document for id: $document.find('body').append(element);